# Localization Not Working in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, localization

I had recently added localization to my Android app which is working properly when the package format is apk. However, after changing the package format to aab and releasing to Google Play store, the localization stops working. Directly deploying to a phone with release configuration and aab package format also results in localization not working after trying to change language.

The app behaves as if there are not resource folders with multi-language translations. To be clear I don't think the fault is in my code since it is working when package format is apk. I have followed the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization

Visual Studio Version 16.11.3

Comment: Can you give us more detail about your Resource folder and the different language files?

Comment: My mistake. It has been pointed out to me that while installing a bundled application from Google Play, only the resources that are required for that particular user will be installed, which also includes language resources which are required for the locale. https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure-base#handling_language_changes